# How to use firebase authentication for different types of users to access their respective realtime database nodes or childs

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an ecommerce android app with Firebase how can I isolate different users like Customer and Seller in Firebase Authentication and give access to read and write to their respective database nodes in Firebase Database(Realtime Database)

Comment: You might want to start with the documentation on [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/), especially the part about [securing user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security).

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using a database structure similar to this:

```
{
    "users": {
        "someUserId-782nafdca9": {
            "name": "Joe Smith",
            "type": "customer",
            ...
        },
        "someUserId-78sdfgs523": {
            "name": "Example Supplier Co.",
            "type": "seller",
            ...
        }
    },
    "dataForSellers": {
        ...
    },
    "dataForCustomers": {
        ...
    }
}
```

with the following rules:

```
"rules": {
    "users": {
        "$uid": {
            ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
            ".write": "auth.uid == $uid",
        }
    },
    "dataForCustomers": {
        ".read": "auth != null && root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('type').val() == 'customer'",
        ".write": "auth != null && root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('type').val() == 'customer'"
    },
    "dataForSellers": {
        ".read": "auth != null && root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('type').val() == 'seller'",
        ".write": "auth != null && root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('type').val() == 'seller'"
    }
}
```

Security rules have a number of [predefined variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#predefined_variables) that can be used to check various conditions. The rules above make use of the `auth` and `root` variables.

The rules for user data under `users/$userId`, currently only check to see if the current user matches the user data they are trying to modify (`auth.uid == $uid`).

The rules for `dataForCustomers` and `dataForSellers` first check if the user is logged in (`auth != null`) and then check that their user data (accessed by `root.child('users').child(auth.uid)`) contains the correct value for `type`.

**Note 1**: As [@Doug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807126) mentioned in their comment, the documentation for security rules can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) with further specifics on [securing user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security).

**Note 2**: Like the official documentation, this example is not without flaws. For example, at any time with the security rules as above, if a user is logged in, they can:

- change themselves between customer and seller if they are logged in to your database.
- add garbage to your database
- delete any data made by other users (no concept of "author")

**Note 3**: Don't just nest all your data under "dataForSellers" and "dataForCustomers", these were given as placeholder names for your own data trees such as "products", "shipping", "orders", etc.

**Note 4**: As you are just beginning with the RTDB, make sure to have a look at the [RTDB vs. Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore) article. For ecommerce, you might be better off using Firestore instead just for it's filtering alone.

Comment: Great answer Sam!